# Can societal morals develop with no concept of religion?

Tags: ethics, philosophy-of-religion

My question is summed up in the title.

Is it possible for a group of people who are completely devoid of religion to develop a set of common morals that differentiate between right and wrong? How would these develop? Would they be firm like Christian morals or would they be more ambiguous? Are there any real world examples of this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to determine good and evil in a vacuum?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/39647/is-it-possible-to-determine-good-and-evil-in-a-vacuum)

Comment: Hi, welcome to the philosophy SE. This question has already been addressed in another post - see the answers and links within. Also, see [Kant's categorical imperative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_imperative), and [Utilitarianism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utilitarianism).

Comment: Yes, I believe our Nursery Rhymes, children's Stories, Songs and Sitcoms are a way to teach these with out religion, and I think they once did, I remember every sitcom was a parable or moral.
Mho

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68168/discussion-on-question-by-bobdylan-can-societal-morals-develop-with-no-concept-o).

Answer (score 1):

For a real-world example: [monkeys have a sense of fairness](https://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2003/09/0917_030917_monkeyfairness.html), but do not have religion-based morals. Thus they have morals without religion. Similar examples could likely be given for early humans, had someone been there to make observations.

Young children also quickly develop a sense of fairness; long before they can understand anything about religion (apologies for the oxymoron).

Answer (score 1):

Philosophy is one way to arrive at morals without religious support. This is indeed a good backing of religious morality, to give people who aren't going to philosophize all day, a book on religious code of conduct.

A good example of the above, is to realize that most religions converge on most issues of morality, even though the histories of said religions might have been completely different.

Answer (score 1):

Jonathan Haidt (The Righteous Mind) and Jesse Graham identify at least five innate moral foundations.  Some focus on the individual and others on the community.  The tension between multiple individual and communal foundations guarantee there will be conflicting moral paths to choose from.  That these are innate means they are present prior to rationalization and culture.  One of them is “Sanctity/Degradation”.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moral_foundations_theory) and YouTube offer overviews of the idea.

If religion is restricted to a cultural product, then a specific religion is not required for morality which has an innate foundation.  However, because one of those innate foundations include sanctity, a foundation for religion in general is also innate.  Religion may be the likely way our species expresses this moral foundation.  Other species may do this differently and have different foundations.

I don’t think moral foundations theory considers other species.  The data comes from our species.  However, given morality as innate in humans I think we should allow for the possibility that in some way such foundations may be present in other species as well.

Given the above, I would rephrase the question as asking: “Can *human* societal morals develop with no concept of *sanctity/degradation*?  Then my answer would be “no” based on Haidt’s research because the sanctity/degradation moral foundation is innate.  An answer to the original question would require separating religion from the sanctity/degradation moral foundation perhaps by thinking of it more as “purity” than “sanctity”.  Although no specific religion is necessary, I suspect some kind of cultural, religious or spiritual, response would be expected since we all share the sanctity/degradation moral foundation and I see no reason for us to keep this to ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely.  I'd look to the framers of the US Constitution--the Bill of Rights supplants any religious doctrine in US society.  Most modern democracies are likewise non-secular.

The relationship of religion to ethics is likely a function of limited understanding of the natural world and primitive mathematics. *(Without rational explanations for natural phenomena, one is left with only imagination to fill in the blanks, unless one takes a strictly rational, Socratic approach.)*  Once you have advanced mathematics, you can start analyzing issues such as economic and material disparity.

Religion is partly used as a method of contextualizing suffering, which is often the result of disparity/disequilibrium.

Comment: US Constitution is a bad example, all framers were Christians, and much is borrowed from English common law, which developed under strong influence of [canon law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_law). The OP asks about development, so as long as secularism developed out of monotheistic societies it is not a relevant example.

Comment: I can see how mathematics might model behavior, but it doesn't in any way serve as a normative standard for behavior.

Comment: @Conifold I'd say the framers were nominally Christians (even today, all US Presidential candidates must claim to be non-atheists) but driven by Masonic and Enlightenment-era ideas.  I'm not sure why origin in monotheistic societies would disqualify the example.

Comment: Not yet, but we've only had calculus for about 400 years, Game Theory for less than 100, and Machine Learning is only in its infancy, but is already proving to be quite good at tracking patterns of human behavior.   Nevertheless, the US constitution is specifically secular and establishes a normative standard for the society.

Comment: Because the question is whether it could have developed without monotheism as a predecessor. Free masonry and Enlightenment do not work for the same reason, they are transparent heirs of medieval Christendom.

Comment: @Conifold I'd counter that these framers may have been atheists, and in that context, the document could be understood to be "devoid of religion".  The ten commandments are not enshrined, but rather the idea that all people are created equal.  This represents a fairly dramatic break, not restricted to the US.

Comment: This is beside the point. It matters not if they were atheists (even if this was historically tenable), how the document is understood or what is enshrined in it, whether it is a break, etc. A catalyst is not among the products of a chemical reaction, but you can not establish that the reaction can proceed without it by citing reactions where it was used.

Comment: @Conifold The problem with your argument, as I see it, is the implication that morality cannot exist absent superstition.  I'd posit, based on Evolutionary Game Theory, that morality, as interpreted and enshrined by the great religions, was merely interpretation of evolutionary traits in organisms for which cooperative (altruistic) behaviors have benefits.  Natural law comes first.  More simply put, I'm unconvinced ethics derive from religion, as opposed to religion serving as a tool (ideally) to propagate reinforce beneficial ideas and social behaviors.

Comment: I am not making any argument, nor do I question the conclusion of yours, I am only pointing out why your argument is invalid. This is not to say that the conclusion can not be defended, but you need better ways of doing so. In the last comment you are not even arguing for the OP relevant conclusion, that a development without monotheism is possible. It may well be that morality developed for evolutionary reasons but monotheism was an unavoidable intermediary and/or catalyst. What you need instead are examples of morality in pre-monotheistic societies.

Comment: @Conifold we're clearly seeing the question in different ways.  I could certainly postulate how such a society would create an ethical standard, devoid of religions idea.  (Possibly that would strengthen my proposed answer?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68165/discussion-between-conifold-and-dukezhou).

Answer (score 0):

Nobody knows what religion means, so this is not one question, but a collection of them.  I would claim that for three prominent meanings the answers are not consistent.

Literally, from its etymology and earliest usage, religion is simply 'the link back' -- whatever binds you to an earlier history.  Everyone has that, and brings it with them.  That would give the answer 'no', whatever you come forward from, you are bound back to it.

In one modern sense, religion is about relationships to the supernatural.  But that requires a later notion of the natural to be interposed after the tradition has lost its claim to accurately explain nature.  Until it becomes obvious that people are maintaining it out of context, what we now think of as a religion is just immature science (including rational psychology as a science).

Only once the choice is made to maintain its truth whether or not it really fits to the context, because it supports meaning and a given psychology, can there be a notion of anything supernatural -- up until that point, there was just nature, and the system explained that nature.  It assumed we knew on its basis how people worked, naturally, and what was ultimately best for them.

So although they had intricate ritual habits and strong theories of how the universe worked, from [one POV](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486242641.html), Homer preserves evidence that at some point Greeks seem to have had no criterion to separate religion from simple knowledge.  So your answer is 'yes', primitive cultures that arise without an already separately identified science should logically all naturally lack the concept of religion in this sense.

In another modern sense, the sense in which Confucianism is one, a religion is a collected set of principles whose effects are enforced by an institution.  That approach gives the opposite answer for exactly the same reason.  A government is an institution, and any set of principles either is religious, or will be soon enough, because the world changes, and we choose for certain things not to change with it.

Comment: Pardon me jobermark, but I felt it necessary to downvote this answer for its lack of grasp of religion. Even the first clause of the first sentence is dodgy. I've never before seem 'religion' defined as 'the link back' and as a religious person do not believe in the supernatural. It's an opinion and valid as such but does religion no favours.

Comment: @PeterJ  I don't care what you have and have not seen, that is the etymology of the word itself an therefore its meaning in Latin.  If you feel I don't grasp religion, you could present evidence instead of bias.  I have no intention of doing favors, I am recording facts.  People do espouse these definitions, whether or not you approve.  I cited Snell for a reason.

Comment: Pardon me for holding a different view and please don't let us fall out, but I must stick to my guns.  'To bind' is part of the etymology of religion but is not its full meaning or even its common one in modern language, and it need not mean 'bind to the past'. Meanwhile my religion states there is no such thing as the 'supernatural'. As for idea that 'religion is immature science' this is a reflection of your understanding of religion. It is a rude, contemptuous, ill-informed and inflammatory remark and you should expect some serious flak.   . .

Comment: @PeterJ OK, and did you see that this is *one modern view*?  Did you read closely enough to see that the fact people will disagree because there are too many different sources for this definition is entirely the point of the entire post?  This is a reflection of ONE OF THE THREE DIFFERENT definitions of religion that I list to DEMONSTRATE LACK OF AGREEMENT.  You never read what I wrote through before you object, and I am really, really sick of that.

Comment: @PeterJ I will not continue to put up with this incredibly unequal kind of argument where you speak but do not listen.  If you think I am stupid enough that each of these three contrasting definitions is my personal definition that you claim to take issue with, there is no point in arguing with me.  Because not to see that everyone is probably going to reject at least two of three contrasting options, and may reject all of them, would require that I be rather a moron.

Comment: @PeterJ  We 'fell out' three or four times back, the first time you were this unfair.  And we will have this problem every time you do it again.

Comment: @PeterJ  I have not advanced the idea that 'religion is immature science', either, even as a corollary of the one definition you have the most problem with.  From the POV that religion is about explaining things, it is still different from science -- it includes either transcendental (if you dislike supernatural) or psychological aspects that are meant to be linked to its explanations.  Science doesn't, or we would have as much trouble changing theories as people have abandoning their religions.  Again, you hear what you want to challenge, and not what is said.  Still sick of it.

Comment: Do you really define science as merely natural science? I thought it was a method, not an restriction on what we are allowed to study. You would have a hard time showing that Buddhism is not a science of mind in strict  Popperian terms and all natural phenomena are explained by it. I find your view of religion rather 'mid-West' and narrow, as if you have not explored it deeply. Maybe I'm wrong, but your post seems to make your views clear. It still seems to me that you regard religion as immature science but if you say so I'll accept this may be not quite what you meant to imply.

Comment: Religion IS science when practiced as a science. Indeed, I'd say this is the best methodology.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71207/discussion-between-jobermark-and-peterj).

Comment: No maybe about it, you are wrong.

Comment: Hmm. Perhaps you'll be able to convince me. I've replied in the chat room.

Comment: Past experience says this will be impossible.  And I will not try.  I don't care to tell you anything.  Just to get you to stop lying about me.

Comment: I feel I owe you some more explanation and came back to say some conciliatory things, but the more I read your answer the more I object to it, so I fear I must stick to my guns. Your three views are three of twenty.

Comment: @PeterJ  And what would including the other seventeen help in any way?  The point is that everyone has their own pet definition here and will allow no flexibility.  So all the answers here can only provide bias and not content.  You are just demonstrating my point.  As I point out modern critics need at least two definitions because no one can decide whether things like Confucianism are religions also Taoism by-the-book, or even the modern 'FGC' version of Hicksite Quakerism.  Pick any definition you want, or any three, and you won't have an answer to the question.

Comment: @PeterJ  This is like the fourth time you have broadly and completely missed my point and then made a long conversation in which no clarification was ever good enough.  Sorry.  I do not care to repeat this.  Ever.  'Conciliatory things' aside, you evidently simply cannot understand what I mean, apparently ever.